# HTML5 & CSS3 fixed navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create my first website manually, and I have a few questions on how to do things. Please note I want to accomplish this in pure HTML5, no JS. All I have right now is a navigation header, which should stay fixed at the top of the page no matter how far one scrolls. However, in order to get an image to respect this header size, I've had to resort to using css in the following manner:

```
main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Is there a a more elegant way to accomplish this? Additionally, is there a more relative way to accomplish spacing than using px? I know about rem for font, but is there anything similar for spacing? My reading indicates that retina screens honor a 2px conversion, but what about 4k screens?

Also, how do I center text vertically in the header spacing?

Lastly, how do I reference a locally installed font on a person's desktop, hopefully negating the need to download a font from the server?

css3

```
* { all: unset }


@font-face {
    font-family: 'biolinum';
    src: url('LinBiolinum_R.woff'),
         local('Linux Biolinum O');
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.image {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
}

main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: -1;
}

nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'biolinum';
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    color: #465053;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
    font-family: 'biolinum';
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #465053;
    text-align: justify;
}

title {
    display: none;
}
```

html5

```
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel='icon' href='images/logo.svg'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
    </head>

    <body id='index' class='home'>
        <header>
            <a href='#'>
                <img src='images/name.svg' class='logo'>
            </a>
            <nav>
                <a href='index.html'>about</a>
                <a href='#'>design</a>
                <a href='#'>analysis</a>
                <a href='#'>contact</a>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <main>
            <img src='images/temp.png' class='image'>
            <img src='images/temp.png' class='image'>
            <img src='images/temp.png' class='image'>
            <img src='images/temp.png' class='image'>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle to show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create my first website manually, and I have a few questions on how to do things. Please note I want to accomplish this in pure HTML5, no JS. All I have right now is a navigation header, which should stay fixed at the top of the page no matter how far one scrolls. However, in order to get an image to respect this header size, I've had to resort to using css in the following manner:
>
> Is there a a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Another way to do it is like this:

```
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
header {
    height: 20vh;
}
main {
    height: 80vh;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Whether you think that is more or less elegant is up to you.

> Additionally, is there a more relative way to accomplish spacing than using px? I know about rem for font, but is there anything similar for spacing? My reading indicates that retina screens honor a 2px conversion, but what about 4k screens?

You can use "vh" as I did above, which is percentage of viewport height.

> Also, how do I center text vertically in the header spacing?

```
nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will center the text within the nav.

> Lastly, how do I reference a locally installed font on a person's desktop, hopefully negating the need to download a font from the server?

```
p {
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
}
```

If it is installed on the users desktop you should be able to reference it like this.